# Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to Enum using reflections

Tags: c#, reflection, types, casting

I have a method which converts `DataTable` to `List<T>`. It was working fine until I had `bit` column in my `MySql` database. It was unable to convert `bit` value `1` to `C#` type `bool`. So I tried to convert it like

```
Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType);
```

where `value` is something that database returned and `prop` in `PropertyInfo` where `value` will be assigned.

It worked fine but it broke how enums were added.

e.g. previously I was able to assign integer to enum field but now getting an error

> Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'EnumsAndConstants.QuestionType'.

I know one solution could be converting `value` to type only when `TypeCastingException` occurs but I don't want exception to occur at all. Is there any concrete solution that work for all types?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: is [Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netframework-4.8) is what you looking for?

Answer (score 11):

You could check [`prop.PropertyType.IsEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isenum?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_IsEnum) in an `if` statement and use [`Enum.ToObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.toobject?view=netframework-4.8) like so:

```
if (prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
{
    return Enum.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, value);
}
else
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType);
}
```